# Updating a global dict from multiple threads

Tags: python, dictionary, global, apscheduler, sanic

I have the following application that runs a scheduler to periodically update the state of a global variable (dict):

```
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import text
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import bumper

app = Sanic()
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

inventory = {1: 1, 2: 2}

@scheduler.scheduled_job('interval', seconds=5)
def bump():
    bumper.bump()


@scheduler.scheduled_job('interval', seconds=10)
def manual_bump():
    global inventory
    inventory[2] += 1


@app.route("/")
async def test(request):
    return text(inventory)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    scheduler.start()
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

The function imported in the 5-second interval job is in a different file in the same directory:

```
from app import inventory

def bump_inventory():
    inventory[1] += 1
    print('new', inventory)
```

This however doesn't work as I had hoped it would. The imported function updates the inventory but the change is never propagated to the original dictionary so either `bump_inventory` is working on a copy of `inventory` or it never updates it outside of the function scope. In two different terminals:

```
]$ python app.py
2017-02-19 14:11:45,643: INFO: Goin' Fast @ http://0.0.0.0:8000
2017-02-19 14:11:45,644: INFO: Starting worker [26053]
new {1: 2, 2: 2}
new {1: 3, 2: 2}

]$ while true; do curl http://0.0.0.0:8000/; echo; sleep 1; done
{1: 1, 2: 2}
...
{1: 1, 2: 3}
...
```

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Still not sure why the shared variable is not updated (my guess is still that it's a copy) but passing it into the function as an argument works just fine (since we're passing references to an object, not the actual object). Modifying the 5-second interval to this works:

```
@scheduler.scheduled_job('interval', seconds=5)
def bump():
    global inventory
    bumper.bump(inventory)
```

This also removes the cyclical import (i.e. removes `from app import inventory`) in the other file.

Answer (score 6):

1- There's no need to use `apscheduler` with asyncio. You have all the facilities you need built into the asyncio and it plays well with Sanic.

2- Using global state is not advisable, especially in a web application scenario. You should use a database, or Redis. But if you need application state for some reason you can store it right on the `app` object.

The next release of Sanic will have an `add_task` method for you to add asyncio tasks to your application. You can install the master branch from Github if you want to use this now:

```
import asyncio
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import text

app = Sanic()
app.inventory = {1:1, 2:2}


async def five_second_job(app):
    while True:
        app.inventory[1] += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


async def ten_second_job(app):
    while True:
        app.inventory[2] += 2
        await asyncio.sleep(10)


@app.route("/")
async def test(request):
    return text(app.inventory)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.add_task(five_second_job(app))
    app.add_task(ten_second_job(app))
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=9000)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still fairly new to the asyncio stuff so this is very useful information. The reason I want to have global state is to not bother with a database and hold everything in memory. An in-memory SQLite DB is also an option but the data in the inventory is very simple (perfect for a simple thread-safe dict) so it seems like overkill. What is the advantage of holding the global state in `app` rather than as a separate variable?

Comment: Also, any guesstimate when a release that includes `add_task` will be available in PyPI?

Comment: This was relevant for me carrying a dict of "session pairs" to "websocket objects", so I don't have to poll the database incessantly to find out when app-state changes.  So, it's giving me push notifications on state changes as they're added to the database.